# Deserializing Json object gets a "null field"

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I've been struggling as to figure out why I get a null field while deserializing a json object

```
public OAuthResponse Get(OAuthRequest TEntity)
    {
     OAuthResponse Oauthresponse = new OAuthResponse();
        using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient c = GetHttpClient())
        {
            string SerializedEntity = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TEntity);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(SerializedEntity);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(MessageType);

            HttpResponseMessage Response = c.PostAsync(_Path, content).Result;

            string Json = Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            Oauthresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthResponse>(Json);
        }
}
```

When getting to the line :

```
string Json = Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

and hovering to "Json", everything seems fine since no fields are null

Deserializing on the next line assigns the deserialized json object to a OAuthResponse object, but somehow leaving one field as null.

Is it an encoding problem? in the API documentation, it is saying that the encoding must be set to System.Text.Encoding.Default.

adding lines like

```
content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Clear();
content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("Default"); // "Default" or "utf-8"
```

do not help.

All fields' name in my class match the keys of the json object and their type is identical.

I'm pretty sure this is a simple question but I'm stuck at this point.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the line

```
string Json = Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

is wrong. Use:

```
string Json = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

instead. Debugging can be weird using async fuctions.

**[Edit]**

I dont know the class `OAuthResponse` so I assumed it to be something like that:

```
public class OAuthResponse
{
   public string access_token;
   public string token_type;
   public int expires_in;
   public int created_at;
   public string refresh_token;
   public string scope;
}
```

Then these three lines are working:

```
    string Json = "{\"access_token\":\"18312b7c108b6084e1e48afjklem51c357733ba1751d1c746e2698304b0‌​83cd6\",\"token_type\":\"bearer\",\"expires_in\":7776000,\"refresh_token\":\"995b‌​04af1d408240egkt85ee560a5571f503cecee294fd241abef3e1b8deda9df5\",\"scope\":\"publ‌​ic\",\"created_at\":1454239878}";
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    OAuthResponse Oauthresponse = ser.Deserialize<OAuthResponse>(Json);
```

Comment: hey thank you for your answer. If I do that I have to change my method to public async, and in that case Visual Studio tells me that the return type  must be "void"  or  "Task"

Comment: This is correct. Or you use the non Async version of the function. If it exists.

Comment: Your return type is then `Task<OAuthResponse>`

Comment: This is getting complicated, I'm changing my Iservice interface, my service locator and my Oauth service class. I'll get to it and tell you how it went thank you

Comment: Ok I did all of that, but I still have the same error.... another idea? thank you so much for your time !

Comment: I must have the value of `Json` to investigate in there.

Comment: "{\"access_token\":\"18312b7c108b6084e1e48afjklem51c357733ba1751d1c746e2698304b083cd6\",\"token_type\":\"bearer\",\"expires_in\":7776000,\"refresh_token\":\"995b04af1d408240egkt85ee560a5571f503cecee294fd241abef3e1b8deda9df5\",\"scope\":\"public\",\"created_at\":1454239878}"

Comment: it is the acces_token that becomes null once Json has been deserialized... these are my fields in my OAuthResponse class:        #region Fields
        public string acces_token;
        public string token_type;
        public int expires_in;
        public string refresh_token;
        public string scope;
        public int created_at;
        #endregion

Comment: Got it !! changed my OAuthResponse Class. Forced Json serialization by adding  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "(json object attribute)")] over each field. Tricky, but I got it!!! Thank you so much for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "JsonObjectPropertyName")] with the corresponding name over each field in my OAuthResponse and changing the names of my fields just did the trick!

in this case :

```
/// <summary>The OAuth access token</summary>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "access_token")]
    public string AccessToken;

    /// <summary>The type of the OAuth token</summary>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token_type")]
    public string TokenType;

    /// <summary>The date when the OAuth token will expire</summary>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn;

    /// <summary>The OAuth refresh token</summary>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken;

    /// <summary>The scope of the OAuth token</summary>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "scope")]
    public string Scope;
```

Thanks!